# How to insert a value from query url to mysql table in node js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Iam new in nodejs, i have a query regarding inserting values in mysql.i have made connection with mysql and now my requirement is to fetch data from query url which i have already done by node js parser.By below code-:

```
app.get('/insertData',function(req,res){

  var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
**var id** = req.query.id;
console.log(id);
connection.query("insert into otps (from_user_id,to_user_id,otp,is_company,status,created_on) values (**'id'**,'2345','1','2','2018-04-04 00:00:00')",function(err,result){

if(!!err){
console.log(err);
res.send('Error in inserting');
}
else{

  res.send('Successfully Insertion');
}});});
```

The problem is when iam sending that parse value (**id**) to my sql table,then null is getting inserted in the table.So how can i save a value from query url to db.

Query Url=http://localhost:1337/insertData?id=20

Thanks `enter code here`

Comment: is it showing id in console ?
use id without quotes in query

Comment: A better way to debug what is happening, is to build your query string before you send it through, then log in console the query and test directly in SQL. I won't even mention the security problems of allowing direct insertion like this.

Comment: it's showing id=20  in console,but when i'm sending it to table ,0 is getting inserted there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are giving id as string .remove single inverted commas (**''**) in query.

```
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "CREATE TABLE mydb4 (from_user_id int, to_user_id int)";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Table created");
  });
});
app.get('/insertData',function(req,res){

  var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
var id = req.query.id;
console.log(id);
con.connect(function(err) {
con.query("insert into mydb4 (from_user_id,to_user_id) values ("+id+",2345)",function(err,result){

if(!!err){
console.log(err);
res.send('Error in inserting');
}
else{
 con.query("SELECT * FROM mydb4", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
  res.send('Successfully Insertion');
}});});});
```

Comment: Hi thanx for your answer but doing this 0 is going in table and on printing same ' id' on console iam getting 20. for http://localhost:1337/insertData?id=20

Comment: what is the datatype u have given for from_user_id

Comment: datatype for from_user_id  is 'int'

Comment: edited..its working for me..can u execute above code and let me know the result

Comment: Thanx ..it's working now ,i think it's the issue of "" in "+id+".

Comment: If you find above answer useful approve it as answer and upvote it